# Doctrine triggering too many database queries

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I've been working on a problem in Symfony for a few weeks and getting nowhere.

Event and Playlist have a one to many relationship. The relevant part of my schema.yml file:

```
Event:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
  columns:
    date:
      type: date(25)
      default: '0000-00-00'
      notnull: true
    name:
      type: string(60)
      notnull: true
    host_title_id:
      type: integer
    broadcast_format:
      type: enum(7)
      values:
        - Radio
        - Live
        - Podcast
        - Video
      default: Podcast
      notnull: true
    long_description:
      type: string()
      notnull: true
    geography_id:
      type: integer
      default: NULL
    has_been_emailed:
      type: boolean
      default: '0'
      notnull: true
    active:
      type: boolean
      default: '0'
      notnull: true

Playlist:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
  columns:
    show_time: string(40)
    recorded:
      type: boolean
      default: '0'
      notnull: true
    title: string(100)
    event_id: integer
    podcast_id: integer
  relations:
    Event:
      local: event_id
      foreign: id
      foreignAlias: Playlists
```

The following code is okay, and causes one query to the database:

```
return Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from('Playlist P')
            ->leftJoin('P.Event E')
            ->limit(1)->execute();
```

The following code is NOT okay, and causes SIX queries to the database:

```
return Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from('Event E')
            ->leftJoin('E.Playlists P')
            ->limit(1)->execute();
```

Worse, with this second statement, the object that comes back has no data in the [Playlists] part. Ie it looks like this:

```
sfOutputEscaperArrayDecorator Object
(
    [count:sfOutputEscaperArrayDecorator:private] => 1
    [value:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [date] => 1998-08-01
                    [name] => Showname
                    [host_title_id] => 1
                    [broadcast_format] => Radio
                    [long_description] => This is an episode.
                    [geography_id] => 25
                    [has_been_emailed] => 1
                    [active] => 1
                    [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                    [updated_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                    [Playlists] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [escapingMethod:protected] => esc_specialchars
)
```

What is the difference between these two orders? I don't understand.

UPDATE: if I change the relation named Playlists to TestPlaylists in the schema and DQL, it works much better. It still fires one query more than I'd expect, but the object that comes back is populated with the correct data.

Comment: I've added an edit to my question above with additional info. The controller doesn't do anything really interesting, it just calls the function whose only content is the doctrine query in the question.

Comment: This is because doctrine doesn't fetch relation by default. So, it needs to make a new query every time you want to fetch a relation. It can be on every line of a listing. If you fetch the relation using a `join`, doctrine won't perform a new query every time you fetch the relation. This problem can occurs also in admin gen list. Solution is to force the query admin is used. If you need more info, I can post a propre answer instead.

Comment: Yeah I think I need more info. Then I can also rep you

Comment: I made some heavy edits to the question. I still don't understand why I'm getting different results with different orders

Comment: I don't know what you really want to achieve. Why are you asking that? Why are you trying both queries? I'm a bit lost

Comment: I'm trying to understand how doctrine works. This code is part of a much larger system. When I take the limit part off of each of these queries, the first one still only queries the DB once, and the second does over 2450 queries and takes over 10 seconds with my current data set. Based on my schema's relation setup and all the documentation I've read, I'd expect both queries to do exactly the same thing, but they don't and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

What Symfony version are you using? I've just tested your schema in a Symfony 1.4.18 project and when I take out the limit from the Doctrine query both of them only create one query to the DB.

If  I keep the limit in there the second Doctrine query created one extra DB query (i.e. select distinct on Event).